# C# Text box currency format

Tags: c#, textbox, currency

Having a form in C# who take data from a select and read the field ancillaryone
any idea how can I show the value in the textbox in pound format like £ 100.000,00? The code is:

```
while (read.Read()) {
    textBox1.Text = read["AncillaryOne"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: With "C~" do you mean "C#"? Then you should add it as a tag to the question as well. And what *is* `read`? What *is* `read["AncillaryOne"]`? Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

if your current culture is : en-GB
else you can provide a cultureinfo as an argument.

you can use :

```
textBox1.Text =(read["AncillaryOne"].ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));

textBox1.Text = (read["AncillaryOne"].ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

this was my test code (my current culture is nl-BE) so i had to use en-GB :)

```
        decimal value = 0.00M;
        value = Convert.ToDecimal(12345.12345);
        textBox1.Text = value.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

Comment: Thanks but it retrieves the name CultureInfo does not exist in the current context. Shall I add on something else?

Comment: Add `using System.Globalization;` or change `CultureInfo` to `System.Globalization.CultureInfo`

Comment: textBox1.Text = (read["AncillaryOne"].ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));  No overload for method tostring to takes two arguments

Comment: is your read["AncillaryOne"] a decimal ? else you need to cast it to a decimal like in my example. If working with a datareader i think there is a method called   read.GetDecimal("AncillaryOne"), with the decimal value you can put the 2 arguments in the ToString() method call.

Comment: AncillaryOne is integer guys

Comment: it works with integer too  , this should do the trick

read.GetInt32("AncillaryOne").ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-GB"));

Comment: I resolved with:   textBox1.Text = (read["AncillaryOne"].ToString());
                    textBox1.Text = "£ " + string.Format("{0:#,##0}", double.Parse(textBox1.Text));

Comment: but did you try it ? because you use a lot of steps to get the same result :)